# How Can I Get The mousedown Condition In for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

I want to get the mousedown condition in for loop.

But I cannot get it even if I mousedown trigger element(ex:#mousedown_button).

How can I get mousedown condition after starting for loop?

```js
$("#mousedown_button").mousedown(function() {
  for_loop()
});

function for_loop() {
  for (i = 50; i > 0; i--) {
    // I cannot get the count_flag(always false even if I mousedown #mousedown_button)
    count_flag = get_mousedown_condition();
    if (count_flag == false) {
      break;
    }
    console.log(i);
    var start = new Date();
    while ((new Date() - start) < 250);
  }
}

function get_mousedown_condition() {
  // get the count flag
  $("#mousedown_button").mouseover(function() {
    return false;
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    return false;
  }).mousedown(function() {
    return true
  }).mouseup(function() {
    return false;
  });
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='mousedown_button'>Click</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet and added jQuery. Please check that the code is what you have

Comment: Why are you adding event handlers in  get_mousedown_condition - they do not do anything `if (count_flag == false) {` is always true

Comment: I think you need to rethink your approach. It seems you are trying to use a loop to get the events, when all you have to do is reactu to the events. I believe you have an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

the way you tried, you bind all the event-handlers like 50 times and their return value will never enter your desired scope, because i am not sure what you try - i just leave this as an answer how you could store your "count_flag" and retrieve it in your loop

```
var count_flag = false;


function for_loop() {
  for (i = 50; i > 0; i--) {
    if (count_flag == false) {
      break;
    }
    console.log(i);
    var start = new Date();
    while ((new Date() - start) < 250);
  }
}

function set_mousedown_condition {
  $("#mousedown_button").mouseover(function() {
    count_flag = false;
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    count_flag = false;
  }).mousedown(function() {
    count_flag = true;
    for_loop(); // start the loop also here instead of override the binding
  }).mouseup(function() {
    count_flag = false;
  });  
}


// initialize everything once
set_mousedown_condition()
```